# Java overloading possible return type

Tags: java, methods, overloading

We have a method `getMessage()`, which we wish to overload. What can be the possible valid return type of the overloaded method?

```
public void kidsCode(String mssg){..}
```

Which of the following methods can be added to the definition of class **`Kid`** without giving rise to any compilation error?

```
void
int
String
```

Any return type

Answer (score 2):

In java overloading can not depends on return type. That means you **CAN NOT** write in java something like this -

```
public class Kid{
   public Kid(){}

   public void kidsCode(String mssg){...}
   public String kidsCode(String mssg){...} // compilation error
}
```

In java to write a overloaded method you have to change its signature.And a method signature depends on the following things -

- method name
- number of method parameter
- types of method parameter

So based on the above facts these are the valid overloaded methods -

```
public int someMethod(int a, int b){}
public int someMethod(int a, float b){}
public int someMethod(int a, int, b, int c){}
```